# R Add a column in nested data sets

Tags: r, dplyr, nested, tidyr, purrr

As a part of a more complex procedure, I found myself lost in this passage. Below, a reproducible example of what I am dealing with. I need to add a column to each nested dataset with the same number within but a different number between them. Specifically, the number has to be what is written in `c1$Age`. The code `cbind(k, AgeGroup = 3)` is only for demonstration. In fact when I used `cbind(k, AgeGroup = Age)`, R gives me the following error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 2.`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

c <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Age Verbal  Fluid  Speed 
2     89     94    103    
1     98     88    100    
1    127    115    102    
2     83    101     71    
2    102     92     87   
1     91     97    120   
1     96    129     98   
2     79     92     84    
2    107     95    102")

c1 <- c %>% 
  group_by(Age) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(db = data %>% map(function(k) cbind(k, AgeGroup = 3)))

#> c1
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#    Age data             db                  
#  <int> <list>           <list>              
#1     2 <tibble [5 x 3]> <data.frame [5 x 4]>
#2     1 <tibble [4 x 3]> <data.frame [4 x 4]>
```

This is what I have now:

```
#> c1$db
#[[1]]
#  Verbal Fluid Speed AgeGroup
#1     89    94   103        3
#2     83   101    71        3
#3    102    92    87        3
#4     79    92    84        3
#5    107    95   102        3
#
#[[2]]
#  Verbal Fluid Speed AgeGroup
#1     98    88   100        3
#2    127   115   102        3
#3     91    97   120        3
#4     96   129    98        3
```

This is what I would like to get.

```
#> c1$db
#[[1]]
#  Verbal Fluid Speed AgeGroup
#1     89    94   103        2
#2     83   101    71        2
#3    102    92    87        2
#4     79    92    84        2
#5    107    95   102        2
#
#[[2]]
#  Verbal Fluid Speed AgeGroup
#1     98    88   100        1
#2    127   115   102        1
#3     91    97   120        1
#4     96   129    98        1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could replace `map` by `map2` and in this way maintain the knowledge of the corresponding value of `Age`:

```
c1 <- c %>% group_by(Age) %>% nest() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(db = data %>% map2(Age, function(k, age) cbind(k, AgeGroup = age)))
c1$db
# [[1]]
#   Verbal Fluid Speed AgeGroup
# 1     89    94   103        2
# 2     83   101    71        2
# 3    102    92    87        2
# 4     79    92    84        2
# 5    107    95   102        2
#
# [[2]]
#   Verbal Fluid Speed AgeGroup
# 1     98    88   100        1
# 2    127   115   102        1
# 3     91    97   120        1
# 4     96   129    98        1
```

When you tried `cbind(k, AgeGroup = Age)` directly, the problem was that `Age` was a vector `2:1`, rather than a single corresponding value.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `map2` to loop through both `Age` and `data` columns and update the `data` columns using `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

c1 <- c %>% 
  group_by(Age) %>% 
  nest()

c2 <- c1 %>%
  mutate(data = map2(data, Age, ~mutate(.x, AgeGroup = .y)))

c2$data
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   Verbal Fluid Speed AgeGroup
#    <int> <int> <int>    <int>
# 1     89    94   103        2
# 2     83   101    71        2
# 3    102    92    87        2
# 4     79    92    84        2
# 5    107    95   102        2
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   Verbal Fluid Speed AgeGroup
#    <int> <int> <int>    <int>
# 1     98    88   100        1
# 2    127   115   102        1
# 3     91    97   120        1
# 4     96   129    98        1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use dplyr::rowwise now, i.e.

```
c <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Age Verbal  Fluid  Speed 
2     89     94    103    
1     98     88    100    
1    127    115    102    
2     83    101     71    
2    102     92     87   
1     91     97    120   
1     96    129     98   
2     79     92     84    
2    107     95    102")

c1 <- c %>% 
  group_by(Age) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(db = list(cbind(data, Age)))
```